# Storing yfinance stock series to dataframe for multiple tickers

Tags: dataframe, indexing, series, yfinance

I'm trying to download all key data for a big list of stocks using `yfinance` and storing that data as a dataframe indexed by the stock `'Symbol'`.

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'BWA', ... ]
factors = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in tickers:
   ticker = str(ticker)    
   try:
      a = pd.DataFrame(yf.Ticker(ticker).info).select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).iloc[0]
      factors = pd.concat([factors, a.to_frame()], ignore_index=True)
   except KeyError:
      continue
```

However this renders a ValueError:

```
line 667, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

How do I make sure the series is passing the stock ticker as the index of the `factors` dataframe?

This is all for present timing for now, but in the future I'd like to store this as a multi index data frame with `'Date'` and `'Symbol'` being the two indices.

Lastly, if anyone has a much faster method of downloading this data from yahoo, please advise. After searching this is the quickest way I could find to do it for a bunch of stocks.